Log Rotation of Docker logs not working properly
enter image description hereI applied docker - Log rotation by creating a file in /etc/logrotate.d folder. Content of the file is like this:
/var/lib/docker/containers/*/*.log {
        daily
        missingok
        rotate 5
        compress
        delaycompress
        notifempty
        copytruncate
        create 0640 root root
}

I applied this file by command:- sudo logrotate -f /etc/logrotate.d/app
Now,
The log files even get rotated, but I cannot see live logs in docker logs command. Help me with Logrotation of docker logs in.
enter image description here
I tried:
/var/lib/docker/containers/*/*.log {
        daily
        missingok
        rotate 5
        compress
        delaycompress
        notifempty
        copytruncate
        create 0640 root root
}

I am expecting that my docker logs get rotated but as well as I should be able to see live docker logs by my command docker logs --tail 100 -f service_name
